# How can I find intersection of two large file efficiently using python?

Tags: python, algorithm, set

I have two large files. Their contents looks like this:

> 134430513
>   125296589
>   151963957
>   125296589

The file contains an unsorted list of ids. Some ids may appear more than one time in a single file.

Now I want to find the **intersection** part of two files. That is the ids appear in both files.

I just read the two files into 2 sets, `s1` and `s2`. And get the intersection by `s1.intersection(s2)` . But it consumes a lot of memory and seems slow.

So is there any better or pythonic way to do this? If the file contains so many ids that can not be read into a `set` with limited memory, what can I do?

EDIT: I read the file into 2 sets using a generator:

```
def id_gen(path):
    for line in open(path):
        tmp = line.split()
        yield int(tmp[0])

c1 = id_gen(path)
s1 = set(c1)
```

All of the ids are numeric. And the max id may be 5000000000. If use bitarray, it will consume more memory.

Comment: Please could you give us some idea: (1) of the max number of entries per file; (2) where all ids are numeric.

Comment: @aix (1)The max number may be 5000000000. I tried using bitarray, but some ids are too large. (2)All the ids are numeric.

Comment: 5 billions entries! how about the domain of values?

Comment: @aix The max number of entries in a file may be 20 million. The domain of values is (0, 5000000000).

Comment: It's very likely that the generator is making this very slow. In general, the less you do in Python, the faster a Python program is: list comprehensions and built-ins are implemented in C, so they may be an order of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Others have shown the more idiomatic ways of doing this in
Python, but if the size of the data really is too big, you can
use the system utilities to sort and eliminate duplicates, then
use the fact that a File is an iterator which returns one line
at a time, doing something like:

```
import os
os.system('sort -u -n s1.num > s1.ns')
os.system('sort -u -n s2.num > s2.ns')
i1 = open('s1.ns', 'r')
i2 = open('s2.ns', 'r')
try:
    d1 = i1.next()
    d2 = i2.next()
    while True:
        if (d1 < d2):
            d1 = i1.next()
        elif (d2 < d1):
            d2 = i2.next()
        else:
            print d1,
            d1 = i1.next()
            d2 = i2.next()
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

This avoids having more than one line at a time (for each file)
in memory (and the system sort should be faster than anything
Python can do, as it is optimized for this one task).

Comment: Does using `sort -n` and comparing `string`s work? s1: "4", "7", "30"; s2: "4", "8", "30" And what about leading zeroes - not an `id`? Are all `id`s of same length?

Answer (score 4):

```
set(open(file1)) & set(open(file2))
```

which is equivalent to using `intersection`, is the most Pythonic way. You might be able to speed it up by doing

```
set(int(x) for x in open(file1)) & set(int(x) for x in open(file2))
```

since then you'll be storing and comparing integers rather than strings. This only works if all ids are numeric, of course.

If it's still not fast enough, you can turn to a slightly more imperative style:

```
# heuristic: set smaller_file and larger_file by checking the file size
a = set(int(x) for x in open(smaller_file))
# note: we're storing strings in r
r = set(x for x in open(larger_file) if int(x) in a)
```

If both files are guaranteed not to contain duplicates, you can also use a list to speed things up:

```
a = set(int(x) for x in open(smaller_file))
r = [x for x in open(larger_file) if int(x) in a]
```

Be sure to measure various solutions, and check whether you're not actually waiting for disk or network input.

Comment: `r = set(int(x) for x in open(file2) if int(x) in a)` might work too. i haven't tested it, tho.

Comment: @Nam: I'd just figured that out, and it works. This way, the OP can even use a list if the files truly contain sets.

Comment: you missed out int() at the end.

Comment: @Nam: thanks. I've moved the call to `int` since it's not really needed for `r`, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

So the algorithm is not necessarily tied to python, but rather generic if you cannot represent all ids in a set in memory. If the range of the integers is limited, an approach would be to use a large [bitarray](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/). Now you read the first file and set the integer in the `bitarray` to be present.
Now you read the second file, and output all numbers that are also present in the `bitarray`.

If even this is not sufficient, you can split the range using multiple sweeps. I.e. in the first pass, you only consider integers smaller than 0x200000000 (1GB `bitarray`).
Then you reset the `bitarray` and read the files again only considering integers from `0x200000000` to `0x400000000` (and substract `0x200000000` before handling the integer).

This way you can handle LARGE amounts of data, with reasonable runtime.

A sample for single sweep would be:

```
import bitarray
r = bitarray.bitarray(5000000000)

for line in open(file1):
    r[int(line)] = True

for line in open(file2):
    if r[int(line)]:
        print line
```

Comment: Bitarrays and in general all kinds of bit manipulation is very not pythonic. In my experience, if I start thinking about bits when I'm doing something in python, that probably means I have chosen the wrong programming language for the problem at hand (or that my approach is completely wrong for the problem)

Comment: Sure, but in terms of efficiency, you probably can't get without. And since `bitarray` is a python-object, you can just use it as such. You don't actually have to care about how it handles data.
Sure generators and sets are more pythonic, but this isn't so bad (see the example I just added).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no efficient way to do this with Python, especially if you are dealing with massive amounts of data.

I like [rumpel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331700/how-can-i-find-intersection-of-two-large-file-efficiently-using-python/7331979#7331979)'s solution. But please note that [bitarray](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) is a C extension.

I would use shell commands to handle this. You can pre-process files to save time & space:

```
sort -u file1 file1.sorted
sort -u file2 file2.sorted
```

Then you can use `diff` to find out the similarities:

```
diff --changed-group-format='' --unchanged-group-format='%=' file1.sorted file2.sorted
```

Of course it is possible to combine everything into a single command, without creating intermediary files.

**UPDATE**

According to [Can](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283032/can-burak-cilingir)'s recommendation, [`comm`](http://ss64.com/bash/comm.html) is the more appropriate command:

```
sort -u file1 file1.sorted
sort -u file2 file2.sorted
comm -12 file1.sorted file2.sorted
```

Comment: There is a better tool called comm.

First sort both files and `comm -12 file1 file2` will give you the differences.

Answer (score 1):

You need not create *both* `s1` and `s2`. First read in the lines from the first file, convert each line to integer (saves memory), put it in `s1`. Then for each line in the second file, convert it to integer, and check if this value is in `s1`.

That way, you'll save memory from storing strings, and from having two sets.

Answer (score 1):

for data larger then memory, you can split your data file into 10 files, which contain the same lowest digital.

so all ids in s1.txt that ends with 0 will be saved in s1_0.txt.

Then use set() to find the intersection of s1_0.txt and s2_0.txt, s1_1.txt and s2_1.txt, ...

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error, I was having two files one for 1GB and another one for 1.5GB around, and when I tried to store it in the set I got an OutOfMemory Heap Size error.

So I have divided these files into 100 small files based on their last two digits so temp1_00 is containing the id with the last two digits as 00 for the first file and temp2_00 is containing the id with the last two digits as 00 for the second file, then I calculated intersection using set for all 100 files and summed it up.

**Algorithm**
Load one file in Set and then traverse second file content one by one and check it's content in Set, if we found then increase the count and remember always store the small size file in Set to save memory.

**Further Optimization:**
The task I was working on just need some approximate value so I have just calculated for temp1_00 and temp2_00 and multiplied the result by 100 to get an approximate result. The error was around 0-5% that I can afford for that large dataset.
If you need a more accurate result then you can calculate for 10 files and multiply the result by 10.

**Stats:**

- **Actual Size ( taking all 100 files ):** 82,595,165 ( 313 Seconds )
- **Approximate Size ( taking 10 files ):** 82,574,530 ( 31 Seconds )
- **Approximate Size ( taking 1 file only):** 85,892,000 ( 5 Seconds )