# handling many huge log files with python

Tags: python, logging

I'm using some python scripts to do statistics.
One sort content of logs are like this I call it A logs:
every A logs has the format of:

```
[2012-09-12 12:23:33] SOME_UNIQ_ID filesize
```

another logs I call it B logs has the format of:

```
[2012-09-12 12:24:00] SOME_UNIQ_ID
```

I need to count how many records in the A logs are also in the B logs, and get the time gap of the two records with the same record id.My implementation was load all time and ID of B logs into a map,then iterate the A logs to check if it's ID was exist in the map.The problem is it casts too much memory cause I have almost 100 million records in B logs.Any suggestion to improve the performance and memory usage? Thanks.

Comment: How many records in the A map? Also 100 million?

Comment: Record in the A log will not loaded into map,just load the logs in B.The A and B has almost the same size.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331700/how-can-i-find-intersection-of-two-large-file-efficiently-using-python

Comment: @nneonneo Thank you,problem is thati also have to caculate the time gap....it seems hard,but i'll try the SQLite first.

Comment: I agree - put the data into a database (any flavour) and then you can play with it to your hearts content. Heck - even import it into excel!

Comment: @EdHeal I think 100million rows just from one file is a little too large for Excel given 2007 onwards only have a max of 1,048,576 ;)

Comment: @JonClements - You can import a portion of the database into a spreadsheet using SQL and ODBC.

Comment: I am not familiar with SQLITE3, but i am very much familiar with MySQL, you may dump your files once in the DB without iterating every raw ()this is much faster then inserting each raw. "LOAD DATA INFILE" t, additionally you may add indexes to your tables, so that the search for duplicates will be even faster, if you must use python, you need to download python MySQLdb package, and of course install MySQL server (i have to say that DB is the choice for doing such tasks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try reversing the lookup depending if "A" fits into memory and sequentially scan "B".

Otherwise, load the log files into a SQLite3 database with two tables (log_a, log_b) containing (timestamp, uniq_id, rest_of_line), then execute an SQL join on `uniq_id`, and do any processing you require on the results from that. This will keep the memory overhead low, enables the SQL engine to do the join, but of course does require effectively duplicating the log files on-disk (but that's generally not an issue on most systems)

**example**

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

db.execute('create table log_a (timestamp, uniq_id, filesize)')
a = ['[2012-09-12 12:23:33] SOME_UNIQ_ID filesize']
for line in a:
    timestamp, uniq_id, filesize = line.rsplit(' ', 2)
    db.execute('insert into log_a values(?, ?, ?)', (timestamp, uniq_id, filesize))
db.commit()

db.execute('create table log_b (timestamp, uniq_id)')
b = ['[2012-09-12 13:23:33] SOME_UNIQ_ID']
for line in b:
    timestamp, uniq_id = line.rsplit(' ', 1)
    db.execute('insert into log_b values(?, ?)', (timestamp, uniq_id))
db.commit()

TIME_FORMAT = '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'
for matches in db.execute('select * from log_a join log_b using (uniq_id)'):
    log_a_ts = datetime.strptime(matches[0], TIME_FORMAT)
    log_b_ts = datetime.strptime(matches[3], TIME_FORMAT)
    print matches[1], 'has a difference of', abs(log_a_ts - log_b_ts)
    # 'SOME_UNIQ_ID has a difference of 1:00:00'
    # '1:00:00' == datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)
```

Note that:

- the `.connect` on sqlite3 should be a filename
- `a` and `b` should be your files

Comment: I have no such a experience, will it takes too much time on inserting records into a SQLite? And i have to caculate the time gap,is SQL support some function to get it?

Comment: @cheneydeng Wouldn't have thought so - no more than a few minutes depending on the hardware... It's one of those try it and see what happens things I'm afraid... http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: @cheneydeng The part that'll take the longest is the `join` as SQLite3 will probably decide to sort the files (which means in effect, you'll be retrieving the results from a merge-sort as Geordee Naliyath has proprosed)

Comment: @cheneydeng Added a basic example you can use as a template

Comment: Thanks.I tried the SQLite3,it'll take almost 3 hours to insert all dates into the database while I haven't use "memory" mode of SQLite.I think it isn't the efficient way to handle my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Externally sort both the files
- Read the A Logs file and save SOME_UNIQ_ID (A)
- Read the B Logs file and save SOME_UNIQ_ID (B)
- Compare the SOME_UNIQ_ID (B) with SOME_UNIQ_ID (A)

  - If it is lesser, read B Logs file again
  - If it is greater, read A Logs file again and compare with saved SOME_UNIQ_ID (B)
  - If it is equal find the time gap

Assuming external sort works efficiently, you end up the process reading both files just once.

Comment: If you presort both files on {id,date} the maximum memory footprint for a merge step would be that of the id with the largest number of matching/overlapping A*B records.

Comment: "If it is lesser, read B If it is greater, read A" ID's are GUIDs not sequential numbers.

Comment: It is not necessary for the ID's to be sequential numbers. The algorithm will work as long as the ID's can be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

First off, what is the format of ID? Is is globally unique?

I'd choose one of those three options.

- Use database
- Union of two sets of ids
- Unix tools

<s>I assume you prefer a second option. Load just IDs from A and B. Assuming that id will fit into 32bit integer the memory usage will be less that 1GB. Then load the datetime of the same ids and calculate the gap.</s> First option would be the best for the requirements.

Comment: The id is a uuid like this /48d4493d-cb57-4505-a64d-b12c89c09dca

Comment: is it 128bit random hash? 200mln * 16 byte prob. be too much.

Answer (score 0):

If the unique ID can be sorted (e.g. alphabetically or numerically), you can batch the comparisons.

Suppose for the example the ID is numerical with a range of 1 - 10^7. Then you could first place the first 10^6 elements in your hashtable, do a sequential scan through the second file to find matching records.

In pseudopython, I have not tested this:

```
for i in xrange(0,9):
    for line in file1:
        time, id = line.split(']')
        id = int(id)
        if i * 10**6 < id < (i+1) * 10**6:
            hash_table[id] = time

    for line in file2:
        time, id = line.split(']') # needs a second split to get the id
        id = int(id)
        if id in hashtable:
            # compare timestamps
```

If the ID's are not numerical, you can create batches using a letter key:

```
if id.startswith(a_letter_from_the_alphabet):
    hash_table[id] = time
```

Answer (score 0):

As the bottleneck is the translation of time stamps.I split this action into many isolate machines which A logs and B logs are generated.These machines translate the string stamps into a epoch time,and the CENTER machine which uses all these logs to calculate my result now takes almost 1/20 time of the original way.I post my solution here, thanks to all of you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the database that has both support for the `datetime` and `uniqueidentifier` for the shown form of the unique id. It comes from Window, and if you use Windows for the task, you can use say Microsoft SQL 2008 R2 Express edition (for free). The two tables will not use any kind of key.

You can use [bcp utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) of the MS SQL that will probably be one of the fastest way to inser the data from the text file (or the  [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) command).

The indexes on the uniqueidentifier should be created only after all the recors were inserted. Otherwise, the existence of indexes make the insert operation slower. Then the inner join should be as fast as technically possible.